# Do all Standard C++ features work in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, c++, c++-cli

If I just include existing Standard C++ class in C++/CLI program, will it work?

In my tests everything worked pretty good, but is it true for every program?

Comment: What do you mean by managed C++ exactly? The original, and deprecated "managed extensions for C++", or the currently supported C++/CLI? I assume the latter, but I won't edit your question/tags until I'm sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what Microsoft promises, yes. (I watched [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-nullptr/) yesterday, in which they explicitly mentioned this -- specifically because the addition of `nullptr` in C++0x would compromise it)

So yeah, if you take a native C++ program and compile it as C++/CLI, with **no** code changes, then yes, it will still work.

And of course, if you change your code (gcnew instead of new and other "managed" changes, then of course, all bets are off, and you might or might not break the code)

Answer (score 5):

If you actually change the class to be a managed (gc) class, then no, it will sometimes break. In particular, the semantics of the delete operator is changed, as the objects are now managed by the garbage collector; deleting an object might not release any memory.

Comment: However, deterministic destruction does occur with stack objects so you can still use RAII.